# Edit css text document from Document Sharepoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have uploaded a .css document to a SharePoint 2010 document library. Unlike normal office documents, when I select the file, the Edit Document button is disabled. So I cannot open the file, and save it directly on the server. I have to download it, edit it and upload it again.

How can I edit such files without downloading them?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Browser File Handling setting in the General settings page for a web application in Central Administration.  If this is set to 'Strict', then it will only open files with an OpenControl entry in the docicon.xml file. Try to set it to 'Permissive'.